# Can't find the origin of the borders around my divs

Tags: html, css, border

I'm creating a print css for a drupal page, of which the theme was created in artisteer. When printed, I don't want to see any borders. The only problem is that I can't find the origin of the borders. I have scanned my HTML and CSS pages and found only two mentions of a border with the color I specified. The other borders in my CSS are all set to `0` or `none`. When changing these to white for example, nothing happens.

Even doing this had no effect:

```
*
{
     border: 0px transparent !important;
}
```

What can I do to find the origin of these borders? Could they be defined in any other way as `border` or `border-color`?

EDIT: I have tried the inspect in browser method, still can't find it.

Comment: just check using this `*{outline:0}`

Comment: Define print specific styles for your elements and assion border-width as 0. Check this link http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: browsers should be the first part to help, check with firefox or safari using "inspect element" in context menu, they can give computed style

Comment: @Uttara That one didn't work. @Rain I have all the print-css in a separate file that's set to `media="print"`

Comment: We'd need to see the page to be sure. It could be perhaps a slightly larger container element with a different colour, giving a border effect. It could be a set of divs to the top, bottom, left and right. It would make little sense to do this but if the layout was designed to allow adding a patterned or image-based border easily, suddenly it becomes a reasonable approach. That's just one possibility though.

Comment: @JonHanna I believe I have figured it out, as noted in the comments below, but feel free to take a look: http://smaakgenerator.phl.be/node/13?sid=38 It's in dutch and still a WIP though.

Comment: Well, if you've found it then hurrah. I'll admit that I couldn't see the cause with a quick look, so well done on figuring it out :)

Answer (score 2):

I would install [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) (if you're using firefox) and inspect this div. With firebug you are able to see which css is aplied to your elements and from which file it comes. Also you are able to change these values on the fly and see what happens.

Comment: I inspected it with Firebug now. Turns out they're part of generated background images. Thank you!

Comment: glad to see you've found the cause. firebug is much more evolved than it's builtin couterpart.

Comment: So it appears :) I only need to figure out the exact origin now.

Comment: If it's the background image, just set `background-image: none`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using something like this to find the element you need to remove the border from. [Inspect element in Chrome.](https://superuser.com/questions/4640/what-is-the-inspect-element-feature-in-google-chrome)

Once you have found the correct element/s to target it should work.

Comment: So you are able to locate the correct element using an inspect tool? Can you show me what styles are on that element and I can take a look.

Comment: As I said in the comment to apparat, Firebug showed me that they're actually part of a background image. The standard Firefox inspector didn't show me this.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry didn't spot that, well you can save the background image and edit it and set it agin in your css using !important. Bit more work but guess it depends on how important it is. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

css selectors have their own [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) and [cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) (priority of effect). so when you have a selector like `#myid` for the element, the universal selector (*) does not affect that element.
you can use firebug plugin of firefox to debug the css.

Comment: Does this even override the `!important` keyword?

Comment: @SimonVerbeke see [cascading orders](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order)